# XLM historical price API

Tags: xlm

I am developing a mobile app dealing with prices of certain cryptocurrencies including XLM. I got a big problem in getting the historical data of the price of XLM compared to USD.

I found many but most do only give daily reports and I need monthly ones. Can anybody point me towards a specific api ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to get daily data, perhaps it's worth using a timeseries library to just get the monthly version of the data?

For example, you can use CoinMarketCap's historical API here: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesHistorical

And can resample using the pandas library in Python: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling